# What's the Objective C equivalent of C structs?

Tags: objective-c

I want to store a couple of NSString NSArray, and UIColor objects together in a struct-like data structure. What's the closest equivalent in Objective-C?

Comment: It depends on how you intend to use the data but a NSDictionary(NSMutableDictionary) should be ok or a full blown class.

Comment: @JasonCoco I'm not sure what you mean - I think there are some quality answers on this question now.

Answer (score 8):

Why not just make a class?

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (strong) NSString *string;
@property (strong) NSArray *array;
@property (strong) UIColor *color;
@end
```

Comment: I personally think this is by far the best solution. Even if you're forced to work with some extremely low-level random access file type, you could just serialize the classes and write them out (which you'd have to do anyway using a struct, except it'd be far more work).

Comment: My question was whether there was a simple way to do this without separate files. I have a struct like class returned from a much bigger class. I just added an @interface to the .h file of the bigger class. I also had to add an empty implementation to the .m file. If the class was used internally to the bigger class, I believe you could put both sections in the .m file.

Answer (score 2):

If using ARC, I would suggest you make a class, as C structs do not allow Objective C objects as instance variables.

If not it is fine to use a C struct, but you will need to make sure you are managing the memory properly.

Comment: (References/citations would make this a much better answers.)

Comment: If you're managing everything correctly, a C struct is fine under ARC too, just flag the object reference as `__unsafe_unretained`. However, this is so much work as to not be practical and prone to error, so much easier to just make a class to hold the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can just define a class to act as a data structure.

Or, since Objective-C is a superset of C, it's perfectly fine to use a struct.

Comment: You cannot store Objective C objects in a C struct.

Comment: @JeamesBone "Huh"? Why not? (Well, generally one would store *pointers* to said objects ..)

Comment: It's possible when using manual reference counting, but forbidden with ARC.

Comment: Yes sorry it's only in ARC, as in a struct they are stored as plain C pointers which ARC cannot track.

Comment: It's also possible with ARC by declaring the Objective-C types as `__unsafe_unretained` and managing them yourself (i.e., ensuring a strong reference to them always exists somewhere else as long as the struct exists)

Comment: @JeamesBone They're not necessarily 'straight C pointers', it's more that ARC can't track the lifetime of the struct in this instance, so it doesn't know when it's safe to release the objects. They're still object references and syntactically the same type of pointer that ARC normally uses. It's not really the same issue as casting (void*) and passing off the pointer.